# Multiple forms using the action variable?

Tags: php, html, forms, file

I have a page that has multiple php forms that send me different informations depending on the user and the form.  How do I make php differentiat these? I saw something about the actions and I thought maybe it was like having a separate file, but when I created a "questions.php" and copied and pasted my php code into that and then added "action="questions.php"" to the  tag, and ran it just as I had before it didn't work.  So what is the correct way to do this?

My code is extremely long and filled with words which is why it would be nice to have separate files for it depending on the form instead of all in the top of my main page.

Comment: When I submit the form it does redirect me to the "questions.php" page, but no email gets sent.

Answer (score 0):

You could build one page as a standard page. in this page you could include the different forms. See the example below:

```
<!-- These are just example names -->
<div class="form-1">
    <?php include "forms/form-1.php"; ?>
</div>
<div class="form-2">
    <?php include "forms/form-2.php"; ?>
</div>
<div class="form-1">
    <?php include "forms/form-3.php"; ?>
</div>
```

If you would like to save data that a user puts in a form in lets say a database you should use the `<form method="post">` by adding an action to it. You're asking the form to send the user to another page when the submit button is clicked. an example of a form down below.

```
<form class="form-1" method="post" action="second_page.php">
    <label>Name: 
    <input type="text" class="input" name="name">
    </label>
    <label>Email:
    <input type="email" class="input" name="email">
    </label>
    <button type="submit">Send!</button>
</form>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I just added a / before the questions.php.  apparently it had to do with file path? I don't understand it but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="questions.php" method="post">
<!-- text boxes to get user inputs-->
<button type="submit" value="submit_btn">click here to go to page in action tag
</button>
</form>
```

If questions.php file is in same folder action="questions.php" is enough. If its inside 'x' folder, correct path should be given as action="x/questions.php"